# Can we use/upgrade Duende Identity server for the .NET Framework applications (4.8/4.7 or below)?

Tags: identityserver3, duende-identity-server

Within our organization, we currently use identityserver3 for our ID server API which is running on .net 4.7.

Is it possible to use/upgrade Duende Identity server for the .NET Framework applications (4.8/4.7 or below)? If not any alternative ?

The all other applications we have as well running on same .NET 4.7/.NET 4.6 using the Id Server API for Authentication/Authorization...